# How to remove double quotations from exported csv file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I have added Maatwebsite package for exporting CSV files from a database table.

And here is my exported class:

```
class ConfirmedExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    public function headings():array{
        return [
   
        ];
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return collect(WithdrawWallet::getData());
    }
}
```

And the result looks like this:

```
"123456789","2100","Desc","lname","fname"
```

But I need to remove double quotations (`" "`) from the words, so the expected result looks like this:

```
123456789,2100,Desc,lname,fname
```

So how to do that?

---

**UPDATE #1:**

I just tried this code for Export Class:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\WithdrawWallet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ConfirmedExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    public function headings():array{
        return [
   
        ];
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return collect(WithdrawWallet::getData());
    }
    
    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'enclosure' => ''
        ];
    }
}
```

And it successfully removes the `" "` from the last element (which is: `123456789`), but still shows the `" "` for the other ones!

[image]

Comment: `str_replace('"','',$csvstr)`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I just added my Controller method with the `str_replace('"','',$csvstr)` but still does not work and shows the double quotations in the downloaded file

Comment: I used the variable `$csvstr` to represent the contents of the file whereas here you have used it for the filename

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius So how to properly use it for the contents of the file ?

Comment: Why do you "need" to remove the quote marks exactly? They are perfectly valid within a CSV file - and sometimes necessary, if the value they enclose contains a comma, for example.

Comment: Have you tried setting `enclosure` to an empty string in the CSV export settings? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/settings.html#custom-csv-settings (Not sure the library will _allow_ that, you'll have to check.)

Comment: @ADyson I need to import a csv file without double quotations to a service of a bank and they say the file must not have any "

Comment: Create a feature request, asking the authors to add a setting such as `enclosure_optional` so that only values containing `"` or new lines are enclosed. Other than that I don't see any useful configuration option.

Comment: @SalmanA Can you create an answer about your suggestion and explain more please

Comment: I would very strongly recommend creating some test that guarantees that fields don't contain a comma (or new line or anything else that needs to be quoted), specifically `Desc`. Hopefully the bank will detect a column count mismatch, too, but I wouldn't rely on it. A simple test would be to re-read the CSV and make sure there are the same number of columns in every row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@nagidi after you publish the config you may change this in the settings.

1. Run following command:

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config
   ```
2. Remove `"` (double quote) from 'enclosure' in `config/excel.php`

   ```
    'exports' => [
        'csv' => [
            'enclosure' => '', // was '"'
            // other settings
        ],
    ],
   ```

Now your csv export values doesn't contain the `"` enclosure anymore.

If you want to change this setting per Export, you can implement the `WithCustomCsvSettings` Concern and add the `getCsvSettings` method to your `ConfirmedExport` class:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;

class ConfirmedExport implements WithCustomCsvSettings
{
    // other code

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'enclosure' => ''
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u mate, but I have used this Export CSV for other files as well and they do need the `enclosure` of `'"'`.

Comment: Is there any way to opitimize it, so if the request is from `ConfirmedExport` Class, the `enclosure` won't be needed, otherwise it have to use the `enclosure` ?

Comment: @nagidi I've updated my answer, this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: @nagidi did it solved your problem?

Comment: I just tried what you said, and it successfully removes the `" "` from the last element (which is: `123456789`), but still shows the `" "` for the other ones!

Comment: I just added an **UPDATE #1** about it. Please check it out.

Comment: Looking at the source code, it looks like setting the enclosure to a falsy value should do the trick unless you're using an [older version of php-spreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1509)

Comment: @nagidi, looking at your updated code, I don't see the `WithCustomCsvSettings` being implemented, this is needed to make the `getCsvSettings()` work properly

Comment: Thank u mate <3

Comment: Just got one more question, is it possible to add extra `,` after the last element? So the result would be looked like this: `,123456789,...`

Comment: You may take a look at the documentation: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/settings.html#custom-csv-settings I think you need to play around with different settings like `line_ending`, not sure if this is the setting you need.