# How to change closure in Maatwebsite package (LaravelExcel) for exporting data without double quotation marks

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I have installed `"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"` and made an Export class goes like this:

```
class ConfirmedExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    public function headings():array{
        return [
   
        ];
    }
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return collect(WithdrawWallet::getData());
    }
}
```

And here is my Model method:

```
public static function getData()
    {
        $records = DB::table('withdraw_wallets')->select('shaba_number','balance_value','first_name','last_name','description')->where('status','confirmed')->get()->toArray();
        return $records;
    }
```

And this is the Controller method:

```
public function exportIntoCSV()
    {
        return Excel::download(new ConfirmedExport, 'confirmedlist.txt');
    }
```

Now I need to export some data from the database table in order to import it to a bank service and the service says, the exported CSV file must not contain double quotation (`" "`).

So now my current data in the downloaded CSV file goes like this:

```
"123456789","2100","Desc","lname","fname"
```

However the expected result looks like this:

```
123456789,2100,Desc,lname,fnam
```

So after researching and getting some help from people, they say I have to change `enclosure` setting.

But I don't really know how to do that and I couldn't find any useful article about it.

So if you know how to change the `enclosure` settings for removing double quotations of the exported csv file, please let me know.

Comment: You already asked about this here, [How to remove double quotations from exported csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69793856/how-to-remove-double-quotations-from-exported-csv-file), so this doesn't really warrant a new question now.

Comment: _"So after researching and getting some help from people, they say I have to change enclosure setting."_ - you could have asked for clarification there then, instead of creating a new question.